# assignment to shared pointer pointing to std::list type does not work

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

i'm trying to assign value to shared pointer pointing to std::list like  but assign fails and gives error and below is my code for reference :

```
struct X
{
   public:
      X();
      X(int a,int b, std::string ss)
      {
         y=a;
         z=b;
         aa=ss;
      }

      int y;
      int z;
      std::string aa;
      typedef std::list<X> Xdata;

   private:
      friend class boost::serialization::access;
      template<class Archive>
      void serialize(Archive &at, const unsigned int version)
      {
         at & y;
         at & z;
         at & aa;
      }  
};

struct Q
{
    public:
       Q();
       std::string q1;
       boost::shared_ptr<X::Xdata> xx;

     private:
      friend class boost::serialization::access;
      template<class Archive>
      void serialize(Archive &at, const unsigned int version)
      {
         at & q1;
         at & xx;   // will this serialize ??
      } 
};


void function_assignvalue(Q *e)
{
    e->q1 = "hello";

    X datax;
    datax.y=10;
    datax.z=20;
    datax.aa="x";

    e->xx.reset(new X::Xdata());  // gives error
}
```

it gives error some unresolved symbols and also will xx serialize ?

Comment: Your compiler already did all the work figuring out WHY it does not work. And it told you loud and clear. And you seem to expect us to do that work *again*. Post the error message.

Comment: "will this serialize??". Does `Archive` class has an overloaded `operator&` for `shared_ptr<X::Xdata>`?

Comment: @nvoigt -  it gives error "LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals" but i'm sure it is related to shared pointer not serializing properly or something else. not sure what is wrong.

Comment: @40two -  this is the complete code shared.. do i need to implement operator& also ?

Comment: Well, what are the unresolved externals?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: As usual, *showing the actual error **verbatim*** is paramount to getting assistance with it. When encountering unresolved symbols/references, the *first* thing you should do is find where they (the symbols in the error message) are *defined* (not declared; *defined*) in your code. If you can't, you just found your problem.

Comment: @MartinJames,@40two - got the issue of unresolved externals solved..but not able to initialize varaible xx in struct Q.

Answer (score 1):

Provide default constructor for your `X` and `Q` classes (see code below):

```
struct X
{
   public:
      X() : a(0), b(0) {}
      X(int a,int b, std::string ss) : y(a), z(b), aa(ss) {}

      int y;
      int z;
      std::string aa;
      typedef std::list<X> Xdata;

   private:
      friend class boost::serialization::access;
      template<class Archive>
      void serialize(Archive &at, const unsigned int version)
      {
         at & y;
         at & z;
         at & aa;
      }  
};

struct Q
{
    public:
       Q() {}
       std::string q1;
       boost::shared_ptr<X::Xdata> xx;

     private:
      friend class boost::serialization::access;
      template<class Archive>
      void serialize(Archive &at, const unsigned int version)
      {
         at & q1;
         at & xx;   // will this serialize ??
      } 
};
```

Comment: providing default constructors - no effect.. still same issue.

Comment: now stuck at point where not able to set value for xx variable.

Comment: i tried below code .. and it works                  
Q::XInfo x2;
e->xx=x2;

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>
```

Will make it serialize.

As for the unresolved symbols, you need to define them and link the objects that define them. See also FAQ entry:

- [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-) external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: even after including above mentioned header files.. still issue exists. I feel it is somewhere in serialization only but not sure where.

Comment: this issue come only with above specified struct only.. if i use some other struct ..no error.. and serialize properly